# Preg_replace giving improper results when Currency Strings are given in Replace option

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, currency

`Preg_replace` giving improper results when Currency Strings like **($1,500)** are given in Replace option.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$amount = '$1,500.00';
echo $amount. "<br />";
echo preg_replace('/{amount_val}/', $amount, '{amount_val}'); // it gives ",500" but i need "$1,500"

?>
```

I tried with `preg_quote`, please have a look at following snippet

```
<?php

$amount = '$1,500.00';
$amount = preg_quote('$1,500.00');
echo $amount. "<br />";
echo preg_replace('/{amount_val}/', $amount, '{amount_val}'); // it gives "$1,500\.00" but i need "$1,500"

?>
```

How could i get exact result i.e. **$1,500.00**

Please help me in fixing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `$amount = '\$1,500.00';` i.e `escape` the `$` before `1`.

Comment: Yeah i got it but how could i add "\", preg_quote is adding both **$** and **.**, i.e. `preg_quote` giving **`\$1,500\.00'** like this

Comment: [Here is a quick demo.](https://ideone.com/ux1wF6)

Comment: How could i escape only **'$'** , functions like `preg_quote` escaping **'.'** too

Comment: @noob: Sorry, saw your comment too late as I posted the answer.

Comment: @Jan: It was an easy one. Not accusing you of plagiarism. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply escape the dollar sign, see [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PKi49f):

```
<?php
$amount = '\$1,500.00';
echo preg_replace('~{amount_val}~', $amount, '{amount_val}');
// output: $1,500
?>
```

Alternatively (is this ***really*** what you're after ???)

```
<?php
$amount = '$1,500.00';
echo preg_replace('~{amount_val}~', str_replace('$', '\$', $amount), '{amount_val}');
?>
```

Comment: How could i escape only **'$'** , functions like `preg_quote` escaping **'.'** too

Comment: @Anilkumar: `$amount = str_replace('$', '\$', $amount);` depending on your needs, that is.

Comment: Could you suggest solution with `preg_replace`

Comment: @Anilkumar: Is your problem beyond just `$1,500` ? If yes in that case you can escape special characters using regex and then pass that string to current code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to replace a literal string, you don't need to use regex:

```
$amount = '$1,500.00';
$result = str_replace('{amount_val}', $amount, $yourstring);
```

Now why you obtain a strange result with `preg_replace`?

In the replacement string each sequence `$n` where n is a digit or a `&`, is seen as a reference to a capture group and is a place holder for the character captured in this group. That's why, to avoid ambiguities, you should escape the `$` character to be sure to obtain a literal `$`.

Comment: Could you suggest solution with `preg_replace`